# Getting a ╠ symbol when working with the character 'e'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm a beginner working through Bjarne Stroustrup's PPP book. I'm writing up a simple program that converts currencies and I'm getting an odd character when working with the character 'e'. The program works as intended when I input a space between the currency_value and currency_type outputs that character when I don't. All other "currencies" work as intended. Any thoughts?

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Currency conversions\n\n";
    constexpr double pound = 1.32;
    constexpr double euro = 1.17;
    constexpr double yen = 0.0089;
    double currency_value;
    char currency_type;
    cout << "Please enter a currency value followed by currency type ((e)uro, (y)en, (p)ound:\n\n";
    cin >> currency_value >> currency_type;
    cout << "\n\n";
    if (currency_type == 'e')
    {
        cout << currency_value << " euro = " << euro*currency_value << " dollars. \n\n";
    }
    else if (currency_type == 'y')
    {
        cout << currency_value << " yen = " << yen*currency_value << " dollars. \n\n";
    }
    else if (currency_type == 'p')
    {
        cout << currency_value << " pound = " << pound*currency_value << " dollars. \n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry, I don't know a currency called " << currency_type << ". \n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't check whether the `cin` line succeeded. If it doesn't, your variables would still be uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

It is seeing the `e` as the computer programming representation for a scientific number, i.e. `6.022e+23`. The other letters don't mean anything, so it puts them into the char. You should read this currency in as a std::string, copy the last char, trim the last character of the string, and then std::stod the string into your currency value.

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Currency conversions\n\n";
    constexpr double pound = 1.32;
    constexpr double euro = 1.17;
    constexpr double yen = 0.0089;
    string curtemp = "";
    double currency_value;
    char currency_type;
    cout << "Please enter a currency value followed by currency type ((e)uro, (y)en, (p)ound:\n\n";
    cin >> curtemp;
    cout << "\n\n";
    currency_type = curtemp[curtemp.length()-1];
    currency_value = std::stod(curtemp.substr(0,curtemp.length()-1));
    if (currency_type == 'e')
    {
        cout << currency_value << " euro = " << euro*currency_value << " dollars. \n\n";
    }
    else if (currency_type == 'y')
    {
        cout << currency_value << " yen = " << yen*currency_value << " dollars. \n\n";
    }
    else if (currency_type == 'p')
    {
        cout << currency_value << " pound = " << pound*currency_value << " dollars. \n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry, I don't know a currency called " << currency_type << ". \n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer and tip. I'm still very early in my learning but your explanation and use of std::stof makes perfect sense. By the way, is there a reason you changed currency_value from double to float and used stof instead of stod?

Comment: @Abdullah no, no reason I did that. I don't remember why I did that either... updated my answer